# Powershell [Ver 5] custom class held as value in dictionary is not updating

Tags: powershell

I've created a Powershell Custom class variable that is stored in a 'value' part of a 'key:value' pair of a hash table. However if I update an integer field in the custom class it also changes another 'key:value' pair.
This is the program

    `class Contact
    {
      [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$First
      [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$Last
      [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][int]$Changes
    }
$ClassMates=@{}

$C = [Contact]@{
First = "Joel"
Last = "Bennett"
Changes = 0
}
$ClassMates['Child1']=$C

$C.First="Justine"
$C.Last="Smith"
$C.Changes=0
$ClassMates['Child2']=$C

write-host "All Class Mates"
write-host "---------------"
foreach ($child in $ClassMates.Keys) 
{
Write-Host $child ":"
[Contact] $thischild=$($ClassMates.Item($child))
write-host $thischild.First
write-host $thischild.Last
write-host $thischild.Changes
}

$C=$ClassMates['Child2']
$C.First="Justine"
$C.Last="Smythe"
$C.Changes++
$ClassMates['Child2']=$C

write-host "All Class Mates After Update"
write-host "----------------------------"
foreach ($child in $ClassMates.Keys) 
{
Write-Host $child ":"
[Contact] $thischild=$($ClassMates.Item($child))
write-host $thischild.First
write-host $thischild.Last
write-host $thischild.Changes
}`


This is the output

    `.\CustomVarTypes2.ps1
    All Class Mates
    ---------------
    Child1 :
    Justine
    Smith
    0
    Child2 :
    Justine
    Smith
    0
    All Class Mates After Update
    ----------------------------
    Child2 :
    Justine
    Smythe
    1
    Child1 :
    Justine
    Smythe
    1`


Can someone see what I've done wrong?
You can see 'Child1' Changes field should still be 0
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's juste because when you create 'child2' you change 'child1'. It's a reference you stock in a key/value. Try :

$ClassMates=@{}

```
$C = [Contact]@{
First = "Joel"
Last = "Bennett"
Changes = 0
}
$ClassMates['Child1']=$C

$ClassMates['Child2']= [Contact]@{First = "Joel";Last = "Bennett";Changes = 0}
```

Comment: Thanks.
So for each entry in hash table I need a new variable of type custom class.
In Powershell is there a way of instantiating a 'new' custom class to the same variable name? [ there could be a large number of entries in my hash table]

Comment: Yes, this is the case, I edit the answer, you need't a var each time.